# ADF running too slowly

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've got a really simple pipeline which fires some APIs, so it's nothing more than just using a web activity.

[image]

When I use postman API to do this it's instantaneous and I get a response straight away, but for some reason using ADF is taking minutes and sometimes it's even timed out at the 5 minute mark

[image]

How do I begin to diagnose the problem?  The region of the data factory is UK South and I can see this warning symbol but would that really affect web activity?

[image]

Comment: When using Postman, do you call the api multiple times in a very short period as well? It could be that the amount of calls brings the external api to it knees.

Comment: I tried to restrict the pipeline to calling just one API and even that's taking minutes though

Comment: The issue affects many other services downstream, such as Storage connectivity (which is basically the backbone of everything else).

Answer (score 0):

As default action, the `web activity` will timeout within 1 minute if it does not receive any response. Though for an improvement, a response timeout property `httpRequestTimeout` in Web activity will let you provide larger timeouts for such synchronous APIs.

[image]

Comment: Hi UtkarshPal-MT, the issue is not that it's timing out after a minute, the issue is that it was running slowly.  But now that the Azure status is back to normal everything is working as expected again so it turns out it was just down to Microsoft needing to fix their firewall issue.